# Calling the same function within another via parameter

Tags: php, class

I have an existential doubt, I can not do that within a parameter that becomes a callback function enter and manipulate the same function, I have no idea what this would be like, but in this example it shows it.

```
<?php

class where{


    public function show_sql( $params ){

        if( is_numeric($params) ){
            echo "Number $params <br />";
        }elseif( is_callable($params) ) { // here validate if function
            // get_defined_vars() <--- I get the variables but I can not manipulate same function
        }
        return $this;
    }


}

$DB = new where;

$DB->show_sql(12)
    ->show_sql(13)
    ->show_sql(function ($object){
        $object->show_sql(14);
    });
?>
```

The result would be

```
Number 12 
Number 13
```

But the number 14 is not shown and I call it in the same function.
I want to have the same result as **Laravel** does in this example: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses go to **Parameter Grouping**

Someone could help me ?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson `->show_sql(function ($object){
        $object->show_sql(14);
    });` I think that here I am making the parameter a callback so that I can use the same function again but I do not know how to call the same function again

Comment: @Bdloul - `is_callable()` works for closures as well. It will return true as long as the variable can be called as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute your callback.

You can use [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) and pass the object as parameter:

```
}elseif( is_callable($params) ) {
    call_user_func_array($params, [$this]);
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked !, how can I know when the callback starts and when it ends if I have several functions inside? example: `$DB->show_sql(12)
    ->show_sql(13)
    ->show_sql(function ($object){
        $object->show_sql(14); $object->show_sql(15);

    })`  Could I use a Boolean variable to know when the callback starts and when the series ends? to get a result like that `Number 12 
Number 13 ( Number 14 Number 15 ) Number 16`  where "()" are string.. 
  How could I do it?

Comment: Just echo the parentheses before and after the execution. Something like `echo ' ( '; call_user_func_array($params, [$this]); echo ' ) ';`. If this answer solved the issue in the question, feel free to accept it.

Comment: it does not work, the result is: `Number 12 
Number 13 
Number 14 
Number 15 
()Number 16` I want the result to be `Number 12 
Number 13 
( Number 14 
Number 15 ) Number 16` with function call like this `$DB->show_sql(12)
    ->show_sql(13)
    ->show_sql(function ($object){
        $object->show_sql(14);
        $object->show_sql(15);
    })
    ->show_sql(16);`
 should I use a public variable of the class where the string is concatenated? How could it be?

Comment: If you do as I suggested, it will work: https://3v4l.org/EmL4V (if you check my previous comment, you see that I echoed one before the call and one after) - Also, before asking more questions, you might want to accept the answer I've already given you?